# translating a website in php or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, translation

i need to translate my site in multiple languages. i was thinking to use a database called language and put the translation there.

```
database : translation
tables:  language
column: id, english, french, german, italian, spanish
```

or i was thinking about a php solution like:

```
english.php
french.php
german.php
italian.php
spanish.php
```

so you simply include the file you need.

now, i can see pros and cons for both, what i want to know is what is consider the standard in the industry to do something like this?

Comment: it's much easier and elegant to create each page : en.php , fr.php... better that querying the DB each time

Comment: i just find the site maintainable in that way !! if you need to change  a translation of a word you need to go the DB and change it !. Let's say chinese people like your website and they need a translation for better experience, you need to go to the DB and change it again which is not appropriate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [gettext](http://php.net/gettext), this function is proposed for this feature,  not a "standard" but fast enough.

The second options in the use of a PHP file with a big array (really big, for each string), this is the most common solution.

To the database content (the big problem here, don't forget), if all your content must have the translation, one column for each language, otherwise use a flag of language for each line on database.

Comment: +1 one of the best things about gettext is there MANY great translation tools for creating files in the appropriate format and it's also easy to submit to several online services if you need professional translation in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no industry standard. I have seen (and implemented) solutions using flat files, XML, PHP code, a database, and gettext files to store the localized strings. It's a matter of what is more suitable for *you*.

My go-to method for PHP is simply files containing arrays of strings, for example

**en.php**

```
return array (
    'How are you?' => 'How are you?',
    'Goodbye' => 'Goodbye',
);
```

**de.php**

```
return array (
    'How are you?' => 'Wie gehts?',
    'Goodbye' => 'Auf wiedersehen',
);
```

This can be integrated into an application with reasonable granularity (there can be many such files, e.g. one for each component) and control (you can easily fall back to any other language if you don't find a string) and it is also very convenient to modify without need for special tools.

My favorite PHP framework ([Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)) and a giant open source project I have worked on ([Moodle](http://moodle.org/)) also use this approach.

Comment: I have successfully used different language arrays and I found it to be the easiest to implement in my existing project (pretty large). Also remember to only load the array you need at start rather than loading all of them them and then picking one, I found it to be a lot faster that way.

Answer (score 2):

Noone of the two solutions seems great to me. You should think in the long run when you think a solution.

What if you choose to translate your website in other languages different from those you thought as russian or chinese? In the first case you have to add more and more columns, in the second you've to create more and more file. Another cons is what if you translate a page in italian and spanish but not yet in french?

I think that a good thing is to have a database based solution and a main language. Now you can do something like this:

- Create a table 'page' (id, title, ...) where you'll store the page in the main language and where you'll have the info of the translated page too
- Create a table 'translation' (idsource, idtranslation, language)
- Everytime check the available translations and give those to the users

Comment: A good solution, though your explanation might have been a bit unclear to someone who hasn't done enough work with databases.

Answer (score 0):

In database localization you have four main strategies. Each has particular advantages and disadvantages. For the long term I would definitely recommend cloning. You can see the four methods at the link below:

http://www.sisulizer.com/localization/software/server-desktop-database.shtml

There are two main ideas you want to be sure to be implementing. The first, be sure you are integrating some form of translation memory. Your language vendor should be instructing you on how to do this and probably doing it for you.

The second, for each additional language you target, your data will get at least 2x more complex. Keep this in mind as you move forward. Not only your data, but your file sets, management, etc.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have further questions.
Russell